# Can not call web service methods from android project emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee

I created a web service based on this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2Vjs8ylmFM)

I can run the service and call its methods, but i want to call them from an android java project. I exported ServiceClient project as jar and i add it to the new projects build path. When i run android project from emulator and try to call a web service command i get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Btw adding the complete exception messege from logcat will help us identify the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: can you send snapshot of your project outline and build path windows.

Answer (score 0):

If Payeli's solution  doesn't work, you can right click the jar and add it to build path using `Build Path -> Add to build Path`. This would include your jar file to the build path.

Another solution would be to right click on the project and choose `Android Tools->Fix project properties`. This option will tell you the best possible solution for build path problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a "libs" directory for the project at the same level as the src directory, and copy the jar file there? If yes, then payeli's solution should work. Otherwise, in the Open Oder and Export tab, check the specific jar file you made. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

first add your jar file in your project.then right click on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to Build Path, which will create a folder called 'Referenced Libraries' within your project.